# How to see how many people are transmitting traffic through my entry or relay node now (live)?

Tags: node, entry

Can I see it any way, and if yes, where, how many people are transmitting traffic through my entry or relay node now (live)? Maybe there are some sites or software where I can see if my node is the entry,  who is connected now to my entry node (their ip's) and the relay node addresses, which now in real time transmit traffic through my entry or relay node, and if it can be in any way to see, 
please write the names of these utilities or the addresses of sites where I can see it.

Comment: From my understanding of the protocol, you can't tell whether cells you receive are coming directly from a client or from an entry node without making reference to external information, such as the list of known Tor relays.  Even then, though, the traffic may be from a (hidden) bridge rather than a client.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is Nyx: https://nyx.torproject.org/